# Fitting zenithal equal area projection with astropy and fit_wcs_from_points

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I'm trying to use `astropy.wcs.utils.fit_wcs_from_points` to fit points projected with  zenithal equal area projection (WCS code `ZEA`). This projection is popular in all-sky cameras.

I have started by projecting a set of celestial coordinates with a known WCS, to see if I can recover it. Input values are obtained by:

```
x, y = w.world_to_pixel(lon * u.deg, lat * u.deg)
world_coords = SkyCoord(lon * u.deg, lat * u.deg)
```

and the projection is:

```
from astropy import wcs
w = wcs.WCS(naxis=2)
scale = 0.095
w.wcs.crpix = [1290, 1950]
w.wcs.cdelt = [scale, scale]
w.wcs.crval = [0, 90]
w.wcs.ctype = ["ALON-ZEA", "ALAT-ZEA"]
```

In all my tests I get the following exception when I perform the fitting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-cfb0b01c0d18> in <module>
----> 1 astropy.wcs.utils.fit_wcs_from_points([x, y], world_coords, 
      2                                       proj_point=SkyCoord(0 * u.deg, 90 * u.deg),
      3                                       projection='ZEA')

/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/wcs/utils.py in fit_wcs_from_points(xy, world_coords, proj_point, projection, sip_degree)
   1076     # and cd terms are way off.
   1077     p0 = np.concatenate([wcs.wcs.cd.flatten(), wcs.wcs.crpix.flatten()])
-> 1078     fit = least_squares(_linear_wcs_fit, p0,
   1079                         args=(lon, lat, xp, yp, wcs))
   1080     wcs.wcs.crpix = np.array(fit.x[4:6])

/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    812 
    813     if not np.all(np.isfinite(f0)):
--> 814         raise ValueError("Residuals are not finite in the initial point.")
    815 
    816     n = x0.size

ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.
```

Things I have tried, without changes:

- pass the actual test WCS transformation in `projection`, instead of `ZEA`
- set `CRPIX` to 0 in my test WCS, so all the points are around (0 ,0)
- remove `proj_point`
- try with astropy 4.2.1 (latest released)

This sample code reproduces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import astropy.wcs.utils
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u

x0 = np.array([702.4, 1480.4, 1223.5, 897, 1916.6])
y0 = np.array([1925.8, 2269.3, 2679.1, 1632.7, 1586.3])
zea_lon = [268.8, 145.6, 181.6, 305.4, 56.5]
zea_lat = [31.8, 54.0, 15.2, 40.6, 16.1]
world_coords0 = SkyCoord(zea_lon * u.deg, zea_lat * u.deg)
astropy.wcs.utils.fit_wcs_from_points([x0, y0], world_coords0, 
                                      proj_point=SkyCoord(0 * u.deg, 90 * u.deg), 
                                      projection='ZEA')
```